# delphi How to click the arrow on the VertScrollBar

Tags: delphi

```pascal
Self.VertScrollBar.Range :=  Application.MainForm.Height;
```

Successfully created a VertScrollBar.

[image]

Pressing the arrow on the VertScrollBar does not respond.

Is it possible to forward messages or set object options?

Comment: Please, do not post ambiguous questions. Include sufficient code, rather more than less. I can not reproduce. Please [edit] your question (see the "edit" button right under the tags of your question). Please read about [mre]

Answer (score 1):

If the scroll bars you show on your screen dump are `TScrollBar` components you dropped on the form, then assign an `OnChange` event handler and do whatever you need to do:

```
procedure TForm1.ScrollBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(ScrollBar1.Position.ToString);
end;
```

But maybe what you really need is a `TScrollBox` which is a kind of `TPanel` with content bigger than visible size and scroll bars permitting to scroll the visible part.